# Десериализация JSON с помощью Jackson на Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

Добрый день имеется следующий JSON файл, который мне нужно десериализовать. Не получается получить вложенные свойства urls. Подскажите, где у меня ошибка или что я делаю не так? Пишу ниже неполный вариант JSON, а только нужные свойства, которые мне нужно вытащить:

```
{
  "description": "text",
  "urls": {
            "small": "any_link",
            "regular": "any_link,
          }
}
```

Также класс, на основе которых будут создаваться объекты:

```
public class Photo {

      private String description;
      private List<Urls> urls;

      public Photo () {
         urls = new ArrayList<>();
      }

      public String getDescription() {
         return description;
      }

      public void setDescription(String description) {
         this.description = description;
      }

      public List<Urls> getListUrls() {
         return urls;
      }

      public void setListImageURL(List<Urls> urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
      }
}

class Urls {
    @JsonProperty("small")
    private URL urlImageSmallSize;
    @JsonProperty("regular")
    private URL urlImageBigSize;

    public Urls() {}

    public URL getUrlImageSmallSize() {
        return urlImageSmallSize;
    }

    public void setUrlImageSmallSize(URL urlImageSmallSize) {
        this.urlImageSmallSize = urlImageSmallSize;
    }

    public URL getUrlImageBigSize() {
        return urlImageBigSize;
    }

    public void setUrlImageBigSize(URL urlImageBigSize) {
        this.urlImageBigSize = urlImageBigSize;
    }
}
```

Сам процесс десериализации:

```
public static void main() {
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   // Прописываю конфигурацию, чтобы не было исключений на ненужные свойства
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
   // В оригинальном файле JSON несколько объектов, поэтому получаю лист
   List<Photo> list = mapper.readValue(connect.getData(), new TypeReference<>(){});
}
```

Comment: Что получаете на выходе, пустой список или ошибку? Добавьте детали в вопрос.

Comment: Была ошибка, впервые работаю с JSON и не заметил, что нет []. А я ждал коллекцию. Пользователь нижу правильно подсказалал

Comment: Если у вас ошибка, прикладывайте текст ошибки вместе с полным стектрейсом в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас urls не список, а объект.

Удалите `List<Urls>`, оставьте просто Urls

Comment: Или измените свой json `urls : [ { ... } ]`

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья, спасибо за хорошее утро!:)))